# EKReminder which was created by stock Reminder app has startDateComponents of nil value

Tags: ios, swift, macos, eventkit

It seems like reminders which were created from stock Reminder app, when fetched by `eventStore.fetchReminder()`, have their `startDateComponents` equal nil.
I have these sample reminders below:
[image: My sample reminders]

But when I fetched and tried debugging, startDateComponents was shown nil
[image: My debug]

I'm not sure what I did wrong during fetching reminders... Because it seems to work perfectly with reminders added from 3rd party apps... Please help!

Comment: Are you sure the date, set on a reminder, is stored in `startDateComponents`? AFAIK it's in `dueDateComponents`.

Comment: Yeah I double checked that I stored the dates in `startDateComponents`. Btw, printing `dueDateComponents` also produced nil value...

Comment: I tested this briefly and the date I enter via the Apple Reminders app ends up in the `dueDateComponents` property. If you store something in `startDateComponents` _yourself_, then it is clear that this can also be read out there again.

Comment: I tried testing multiple times, still no data stored in `startDateComponents` and `dueDateComponents` whatsoever :(

Comment: Some interesting things, `creationDate` and `lastModifiedDate` were also shown as nil, although this is impossible imo/

Comment: Okay you are right, seems like this is more of a debugger problem. `print reminder.dueDateComponents` produces nil output while `print reminder.dueDateComponents!.date!` produces a value. I cannot wrap my head around this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the comments summarized as a response:
For a reminder, the `startDateComponents` property is not necessarily filled. At least, the iOS Reminders app doesn't do this.

The date that can be entered for a reminder ends up in the `dueDateComponents` property.